# How to solve Android Studio Error With gradle

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.03.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', includes: ['*.jar'])
    mobileApp project (':mobile')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.03.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'
```

I seen some stack on stack overflow But Still My error is Not Solved I try to understand previous Stack on Stack over flow but it's not working I post on some group no buddy reply so I post here.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: Error is Gradle acttualy I did not use Stack over flow before yet it's very difficult to upload question

Comment: You didn't provide any error or stack trace.

Comment: Can't upload images don't know why

Comment: Wait I turn on pc will upload code in image 10 reputation need

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter{
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: include ':app'
include ':mobile' in setting gradle

Comment: (24,0) error  could not found method

Comment: @PrashantVyas Sorry, the error is not visible in image. Please paste it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your comments on StackOverflow I guess this is the real culprit,

```
 buildToolsVersion "25.03.1"
```

and

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.03.1'
```

Change it to

```
buildToolsVersion "25.3.1" // remove 0 before 3

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' // remove 0 before 3
```

And rebuild the project.

**Edit**

In order to fix the below error

> Wed Sep 13 04:59:29 IST 2017 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME distributionPath=wrapper/dists zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME zipStorePath=wrapper/dists distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/g‌​radle-3.3-all.zip the buidl file may missing agradle plugin

Download Gradle from their [official site](https://gradle.org/releases/), currently it is [4.1](https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-bin.zip) and extract it to somewhere in your system. (Ex. **C:/gradle-4.1/**)

Now in Android Studio goto **File** - **Settings** - **Build and Execution** - select **Gradle**

Here, by default it is **Default gradle wrapper(recommended)**. Now select 2nd radio button and browse to your extracted gradle folder/drive (in my case **C:/gradle-4.1**). Click OK. (If you want offline mode you can select)

After that click **Apply** - **OK**. Now Android Studio starts building project. This will resolve your problem.

Comment: still not solve when ever I create new project it's appears

Comment: If it appears remove the extra 0 as I said. Post clear screenshots or else cpoy paste the errors that you get in Android Studio. And what is `mobileApp project (':mobile')` in your project's build.gradle file?

Comment: #Wed Sep 13 04:59:29 IST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip    the buidl file may missing agradle plugin

Comment: I seen on stack overflow for create moblie app we should use this (: mobile)